# Can $e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}$ be simplified?

Tags: exponential-function, inverse-function

I would like to find the inverse function of $$f(x) = \ln(x) + \frac{1}{\ln(x)}$$
but I got stuck when trying to remove the exponents:
$$e^x = y \cdot e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}$$

Comment: Note that this isn't a bijection, so it doesn't have an inverse in the formal sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\ln(x)+\frac1{\ln(x)}$$

$$\ln^2(x)-y\ln(x)+1=0$$
$$\ln(x)=\frac{y\pm\sqrt{y^2-4}}{2}$$

$$x=\sqrt{e^{y\pm\sqrt{y^2-4}}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

1. Let $u=\ln x$, to simplify the algebra. Then we have
   $$y=u+\frac{1}{u}$$
2. Multiply this by $u$ to get a quadratic equation in $u$.
3. Solve for $u$ in terms of $y$.
4. Now put $x=e^u$.